# How can I make this less of pop-up?

Tags: html, css

[In this site (password: dizi)](http://dizievents.ch/index.php/event/food-n-liquor-dizinvolta-2/), if the user clicks the <kbd>inscription</kbd> button it will open a new pop-up window.

How can I make the window about half the size it is now?

I tried to add a fixed size: `height: 200px;` but it did not work.

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
     <div class="item-block-title">
            //some code HTML
     </div>
     <div class="fa fa-envelope-o">
            //some code HTML
     </div>
</div>
```

```css
.item-popup-content {
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: solid 30px #fff;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: might i ask why do you want to do that? it hides half the content of your modal making your users having to scroll to fill in the form

Comment: Your link is a redirect loop.

Answer (score 0):

try adding css:

```
.item-popup-content{
    height: 200px; // set the height to whatever you want it
    overflow: auto; // allows for scrolling bar for the contents that spills beyond your set height
}
```